# How to do both ways integrations across different Perforce depots?

Tags: integration, perforce, depot

I would like to know how we are supposed to do integration between different Perforce servers/depots.

I'm looking for a solution that would allow us to do both-ways integrations.

This [Using Remote Depots](http://kb.perforce.com/article/30) article describes how to map the remote depot as read only. Is this the only solution to do mappings on both servers? If so, this means that I could not use a single branch spec to do both ways integrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the Perforce knowledge base, I believe the preferred/suggested solution is for each server to do the integrate from the read-only remote depot.

This is a by-design limitation of Perforce because the meta-data is only available to the local server, e.g. `serverA:1666` does not know commands performed by a user on `serverB:1666` (as explained in the case-study at the bottom of [this article](http://kb.perforce.com/article/30)).

Also the point regarding **performance is absolutely true**; our server was hammered this afternoon during a code drop from a remote depot. All we could do was wait until the integrate/diff was complete.

To find out what is happening on your server, use the command `p4 monitor show` to show what the current workload on your server.

Comment: Regarding your server getting hammered by a remote depot request: Is either of your servers a pre-2010.2 server version? The 2010.2 release had a huge performance fix for remote depots.

Comment: @user1054341: Yes, one or both servers would have been pre-2010.2, I believe 2009.x. It is good to know that 2010.2 and later have improvements in performance. :)